# passing different objects of same base class to method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Basically, I would like to create a Method, that takes a base-class as a parameter, and can be used "generic" for derived classes

ef-code-first classes:

the base class

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

derived classes:

```
public class DerivedA:BaseClass
{
    public string AValue {get;set;}
    ...more specific fields
}


public class DerivedB:BaseClass
{
    public string BValue {get;set;}
    ..... more specific fields
}
```

I call a "generic Method" with these slightly different objects:

```
System.Data.Entity.DbSet<DerivedA> _dA....
System.Data.Entity.DbSet<DerivedB> _dB....

genericMethod(_dA.Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith("a name")))); //<-contains records
genericMethod(_dB.Where(a => a.Id==5)); //<---- contains records
```

Both "Where..." contain records in debug (after clicking on Enumerate)

now the method:

```
public string genericMethod(<IQueryable>BaseClass _myClass)
{
    foreach (BaseClass c in _myClass)  // <-------class is empty - no records
        {
          // do something usefull...
        }
    return someResult 
}
```

But no records are contained, when inside the method.

Is it possible, what I am trying to do...?
Does it make sense?

There are no design-time or compile-time or runtime errors, but the passed object contains no records when passed to the method, but it contained records in the calling statement.

What did I do wrong?

Is there a better approach? -

I need this Method, for manipulation of more than two (maybe ten) derived classes, and therefor I want it "generic".

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure there are no compile-time errors? I don´t think you can use the keyword "class" as a parameter name and your <IQueryable>BaseClass can´t work neither.

Comment: is genericMethod going to get a mix DerivedA and DerivedB instances or just one of the two?

Comment: Ondra - sorry..stripped down code for readability - of course class would not work - changed it to _myClass

Comment: @kabaros: only one of them. but A or B..or C ..D... all of them have BaseClass properties in common.

Comment: This looks like a LINQ/EF issue, not a problem with inheritance.  What if you add .ToList() to the end of your Wheres?

Comment: Are you sure that there is actually data in the database that matches these queries?

Comment: @Servy yes - can enumerate them in debugger

Comment: @Jasper: no luck, still empty when inside method

Answer (score 1):

When faced with something like this, I like to simplify my code.

I would try removing the `_dA.Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith("a name"))` and `_dB.Where(a => a.Id==5)` from the method call and put them into variables first (and then pass the variable into the method).

This will allow you to better inspect your code and perhaps shed light on the problem.

Comment: Alternatively, just remove the Where() clauses and call it on the entire set of _dA.

Comment: While not bad advice, this isn't really an answer.  It might help in debugging, but this refactor won't change what the code actually does.

Comment: "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime." I chose to teach.

Answer (score 0):

add .ToList() to materialize the query before you pass it to the method:

```
genericMethod(_dA.Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith("a name"))).ToList());
```

Otherwise you're not really passing the result of the query, you're just passing a query that needs to be evaluated first. ToList() will evaluate it for you. When you look in the debugger watch, it's basically evaluating it for you on the fly, that's why you see rows returned.

After that, change your method to deal with IList instead of IQueryable.

Comment: When you want to convert a query to an enumeration you can just use `AsEnumerable`.  It has the same effect of making all subsequent LINQ methods use linq to objects, not linq to EF (or whatever) but it doesn't bring all of the objects into memory.  Also, it's clearly not the problem here because he's just foreaching over all of the items, not performing another query on them.

Comment: Interestingly now my call shows a "some invalid arguments" error -but I DID change <IList> _myBaseClass and _Where(....).ToList()

Comment: Tried AsEnumerable() but still no data-records inside the method, when there were records in the object passed in.

Comment: some invalid argument for what? can you give details of exception

Comment: genericMethod(dbSet.Where(a => a.slug.StartsWith(p)).ToList()); <-invalid arguments
for genericMethod(IList<Models.BaseClass> Xisting)

Comment: what if you change to generic method: public string genericMethod<T>(IList<T> _myClass) where T: BaseClass